# matching tarball to a git repository

Tags: git, merge, branch

Given a git repository and a tarball with no revision information.  The tree in the tarball originated from the repository at some point in the past and changed quite a bit.  The repository has changed quite a bit as well.  The commit where the tarball tree was copied from the repository is unknown.  The task is to find the commit which is most close to the tarball, to examine the changes in the tarball tree or to graft the tarball tree back to the repository.

I did this before with manual dichotomic search, minimizing the output of `diff -ruN gitrepo tartree | wc -c`.  I wondered if there is a tool that can automate the task?

Comment: If the tarball tree has changed since it was originally made, I cannot see any way whatsoever that you can be certain to find the original commit. But you could apply it on every commit in the history and see where you get the least changes from what's commited. Once you've found that commit with a minimum of changes, you probably have the commit it was made from, no guarantees though.

Comment: Brut force can be a solution to find the commit with the smallest diff versus your tar ball. But if you don't have any clue on the modification done, you have to define a metric to define the most close. By the way, nothing will guarantee that closest is the original commit

Answer (score 2):

Thank you [fredrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978558/fredrik) and [Ôrel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4605105/%c3%94rel) for the comments.  I understand the original commit may or may not be discoverable, so I said "most close".  I have coded a linear brute force search and it does find a nice extremum much faster than the manual consideration I did before... especially if you guess well from which commit to start the search.

(update: the script shortened by using `git log --pretty=format` as suggested by [LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec)).

````
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Estimate similarity of $DIR to every commit in ```git log``` output,
# output a line for every commit.  ```git log``` starts from the
# currently checked out commit and goes back in time.
#
# The script is quick and dirty: it checks out every commit in turn to
# take a diff.  After the script stops for whatever reason, the last
# commit seen stays checked out.  You will have to restore the original
# checkout yourself.

sub usage {
    die ("Usage:\n",
         "  cd clean-git-repo\n",
         "  git-match-dir DIR\n");
}

sub main {
    my $dir = $ARGV[0] // usage();
    open (my $fh, "git log --pretty='%H %ad'|") or die;
    while (<$fh>) {
        # d2e9457319bff7326d5162b47dd4891c652c2089 Thu Sep 14 09:44:58 2017 +0300
        my ($commit, $date) = /(\w+) \w\w\w (.*)/;
        $commit or die "unexpected output from git log: $_";
        my $out = `git checkout $commit 2>&1`;
        $? == 0 or die "$out\nCheckout error.  Stop";
        my $len = 0 + `diff -wruN --exclude .git . $dir | wc -c`;
        printf("%10u %s %s\n", $len, $commit, $date);
    }
}

main();
exit 0;
````

Comment: Look at pretty formats in `git help log` : it will be easier to parse `git log --pretty=format:"%H %(ad)"`

Comment: With Perl, parsing line-structured text is no-brainer.  But indeed it could be even simpler if I knew about --pretty=format.  Thanks!

Comment: [mandatory xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/224/) ;)

Comment: I would have much less chances to understand the Universe if it were written in Lisp...  Glad to hear it's Perl :)

Answer (score 0):

If the tarball is the exact content of one of your repo's commit, you can search for the tree hash :

1. use git to compute the hash for the tree of your tarball
2. print the list of `commit-hash tree-hash`
3. grep 1. in 2.

---

1. In an empty directory :

- create a repo
- untar your tarball
- run `git add -a && git commit`
- run `git rev-parse HEAD^{tree}`

2. In your git repo, run :

   git log --all --pretty=format:"%H %T"
3. grep the output of 1. in the list produced by 2.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't do as in my case both the repo and the tarball tree have been modified.  We have to match loosely, not strictly.

Comment: wasn't the tarball generated from a commit in the past ?

Comment: You could scan for the hash of subtrees, eg : match `git rev-parse tarball:src/some/module` against `git rev-parse commit:src/some/module`

Comment: Your diff method also works well. Looking for already computed hashes is just quicker than running a complete `checkout + diff` on each commit.

Comment: Diff will cope even if every file in the repo and the tree differ.  Hashes will not, even if taken to the extreme (generating hash for every file in every commit)